# How to add transition to JavaScript toggle class

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, transition

I was making a toggle class in JavaScript in which I have a div which toggles its class on mouse hover.  One of the classes of the div has a colored background and the other one has an image.  The problem is that the image comes in an instant and does not transit smoothly

My css code is:

```
.container{
}

.first{
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.sec{
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    background: url(1.jpg);
    background-color: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="container" class="first"><span>HELOO</span>
</div>
```

and finally my JavaScript is:

```
this.classList.toggle('first');
        this.classList.toggle('sec');
        document.getElementById('#container').style.WebkitTransition = 'all 0.5s';
    }
    document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mouseenter', a )
    document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mouseout', a )
    document.getElementById('#container').style.WebkitTransition = 'all 0.5s';
```

Comment: Why don't you use pure css to achieve it. I think it's much more simple.

Comment: i dont think there is any pure css way to add transition between image, if there is then i would love it because i a m more strong in css than my javascript

Comment: You should read Mohsen's answer.

Comment: What the browser are you using? -webkit-transition just run on Chrome.

Comment: That is no the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can not set transition effect on a background image, But there is some way that you can simulate that. look at this code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8y2C/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>HELOO</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ddd;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
span:hover{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for learning, if you insist using javascript to toggle the class.

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/qtpCS/

Using `:after` technique.

Comment: Lots of work to do with javascript. Obviously, pure css is better.